# Validating a password with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a password program in python?
The conditions for the password are:

1. The password should contain at least one special character and a number
2. Length of the password should be at least 8
3. The first letter of password should be a alphabet

If it satisfies above conditions it should print valid, else print invalid.

Restricted to use of only for and while loops

P.S-I'm learning python in initial stages

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: to make password programme in python

Comment: if it satisfies above conditions it should print valid or invalid

Comment: @VarunShaandhesh what code have you tried to write so far? What are you stuck on?

Comment: i am confused to check whether a string contains both special characters and numbers by using only for or while loops?

Comment: How about regex?

Comment: You can easily write a function that checks those conditions. Just break it down to small steps.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need for loops or while loops. Python has an impressive suite of inbuilt functions to help you with this.

Here's a breakdown of what is to be used where:

1. One special character and a number: Use `re.search` (`import re` first)
2. Length of the password should be at least 8: Use `len`
3. The first letter of password should be a alphabet: Use `str.isalpha`

---

```
In [49]: import re
    ...: 
    ...: def foo(password):
    ...:     return password[0].isalpha() and\            # 3
    ...:            len(password) >= 8 and\               # 2
    ...:            bool(re.search('\d', password)) and\  # 1a
    ...:            bool(re.search('[^\w]', password))    # 1b
    ...: 

In [50]: foo('test123!')
Out[50]: True

In [51]: foo('test!')
Out[51]: False
```

Returning a boolean value is clearer and more readable than returning a string such as "(in)valid" that you'd have to manually interpret later.